# Python script for a specific selection

Tags: python, scripting

To separate an object, I use the edge split modifier in the object mode: 
[image]

then I go into edit mode, put my mouse over the external face and press <kbd>L</kbd>. This operation select all the external part and I can separate it from the rest : [image]

However when I try to do it with a script it doesn't work because I have to manually put my mouse over the external surface... 
Have you any ideas on how to seperate this object in two parts (the external part and the rest) with a python script ?

Comment: if it is for the case select the vertex with the highest Z component than use 'bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()'  or if the edge split modifier result is 2 meshes use separate loosee

Comment: How do you select the vertex with the highest Z component with python ?

Comment: you sort them , go through them and find the max

Comment: I tried to make a script to select the vertex with the highest Z component : 

`me = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:
    center = face.calc_center_median()

    for i in range (100,0):
        
        if  center.z >= i :                
            face.select_set(True)
            
                if face.select_set(True):
                return    
            
bm.to_mesh(me)

bm.free()`

Comment: @poor separate by loose my generate more than 2 objects (depends on the object structure )

Comment: @poor he gave a very specific case in the example , but i imagine in general  the selection would be based on the faces' normals since he said 'external part '

Comment: @poor indeed separate by loose generates more than 2 objects in my case because of the structure of my object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script which :

- goes thorough vertices and find the highest
- select it and what is linked to it
- separate it with separate(selected)

after applying the edge split modifier run this script :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action ='DESELECT')
max = -9999
for i in obj.data.vertices :
    if i.co[2] > max :
        max_ind = i.index
        max  = i.co[2]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj.data.vertices[max_ind].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

#bpy.context.selected_objects[0].location[2] +=1
```